Pause the console with NLog console target?
I'm using NLog in C#. I would like to use Nlog to log on production and display my console (terminal) on local development.
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" enabled="true" />
The console target is described on
https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=targets
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target
My logging system is working fine but one feature is still not resolved for me. When working on my local environment, I would like to pause the console after logging an error. Right now, the system log all on my console but when I have an exception, I don't have time to read it.
Is it possible, when I log a level exception or error to pause the console? Of course, only for development environment when console log is activated.

And yes, I have a workaround at this moment. I use a second target in a file. Classic. When the exception happens, I can read my file. But this is not convenient.

You can setup NLog Logging-Rules to write all errors to a MethodCall-target that calls a delegate that calls Console.ReadLine(). Not sure how to do it when multi-threaded application, maybe Debug.Break or Suspend-All-Threads ?

If you're already logging to a file, I suggest running a tail program, e.g. klogg. You can have it watch the logfile and autoscroll like a console, but also allows you to search, filter, highlight etc.
